# Flutter Chopper Internet connectivity

Tags: flutter, dart, internet-connection, chopper

How in flutter project check internet connectivity and throw a page with text like "No internet" using Chopper only? without data_connection_checker or else

Answer (score 1):

Chopper interacts with HTTP/HTTPS, whereas internet connectivity checking deals with lower levels of the [IP stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite).

You can technically try to make a request, and see if you get some kind of error, but that's not a reliable way. Often if there's no connection, the request will timeout, which could take a while. Even if you set a short timeout, it's much better to use a connectivity client.

The canonical plugin is [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus)